# How can I remove case sensitivity from field formulas?

Tags: regex, looker-studio, re2

I created a new field in Data Studio whose formula is:

```
IF(STATUS= "lost","lost","found")
```

The problem is `STATUS` column contains lost, Lost and many other variations.
How do I make this formula case insensitive in the easiest manner.

I read something about regex and using `(?i)` but that didn't work as expected.

Comment: **Needs details [REVISION 1]**: Provide a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report [TO-DO] and sample data set(s) / shared Google Sheet [TO-DO] of the scenario, that shows 1) Input table(s) (~9 rows) / chart in both Question [TO-DO] and Report [TO-DO] 2) Expected table / charts in both Question [TO-DO] & Report [TO-DO] 3) Issue / attempt at solving in both Question [DONE: Needs context 1&2] & Report [TO-DO]. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to visualise and pinpoint a suggestion to a specific use case

Answer (score 0):

If in the status field the word "Lost" or "LOST" or "lost" or "losT" is given, the text "lost" should be put out, otherwise "found".

For removing the case sensitivity of a field, no regualar expression is needed. The text of a field can be transfered to lower case by the function `lower()`. Thus the formula is:

```
if(lower(STATUS)="ok","found","lost")
```

If you want to search for the word "lost" in a field, regualar expression is a good choice:

```
if(REGEXP_MATCH(STATUS,r"(?i).*lost.*"),"found","lost")
```

The `(?i)` makes the search case-insensitive. The word `lost` is needed.
The `.*` matches any character before or after the `lost` word.